# Google Application Engine resets the TCP connection

Tags: google-app-engine, http, tcp, connection

We observe that the TCP connections are sometimes reset by Google Application Engine. The exact behavior is following:

- TCP handshake is done  (SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK)
- Http POST is sent by client
- Google Application servlet sends RST

See the attached screenshot. Any reason for that? Should we simply send the POST request again on client?

BR
STeN

[image]

Comment: Is your POST producing an error?

Comment: Hi, you mean error on the server side? Like there will be unhandled exception? Our experience from mobile side is that it sometime works, sometimes not. Usually if the 1st POST fails, the 2nd works.

Comment: Almost certainly you are sending something illegal.